# How to restart Vino (or my Desktop Environment)?

Tags: unity, vnc

Following just happened (in this order):

- I was connected to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Unity) via Vino
- Tried to login via PuTTY several times with no success
- Closed my VNC-Viewer
- Tried to login again. Still no success.
- Opened my VNC-Viewer again. Logged out via GUI. VNC-Viewer closed.
- Then I could login via SSH *(and installed java8)*.
- Tried to connect via VNC again. But the server refused my connection.

<sub><sup>Note that my login failures via ssh could have been just me being too tired to write passwords at 11pm</sup></sub>

---

Googled how to restart vino. Found this:

> $ pkill vino

Then to start it again,

> $ export DISPLAY=:0.0
>
> $ /usr/lib/vino/vino-server &>

Did not help. Following error message occurs:

> dnndev@skynet:~$ /usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
>   [2] 20046
>
> dnndev@skynet:~$ Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket:
>
> No such file or directory
>
> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>
> Cannot open display:
>
> Run 'vino-server --help' to see a full list of available command line options
>
> [2]-  Exit 1                  /usr/lib/vino/vino-server

---

Seems like I am locked out of the system now. I won't have physical access to the machine until monday. So it would be really great if someone knows how I can get the VNC-Server up and running again.

I'd appreciate a solution that does **not** include restarting the machine. I really want to avoid that.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that will end here from search engine :)

With information from here:

[vino CLI](http://www.softpanorama.org/Xwindows/VNC/Vino/activating_vino_from_command_line.shtml)

I managed to restart vino server from another VNC connection on Ubuntu with following commands:

```
pkill vino
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0.0
```